# Error: 'There is not exactly one Assertion' Using ITfoxtech Saml2

Tags: oracle, authentication, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I am using Itfoxtech SAML 2.0 with .net core. But I am getting error 'There is not exactly one Assertion'.
Does Itfoxtech with with Oracle Access Manager? Can you give me clarity about the signing and certifications. Do I need to use certificate to get the assession?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909662/itfoxtec-identity-saml2-saml2requestexception-there-is-not-exactly-one-asserti

Answer (score 1):

I do not know Oracle Access Manager, but I would expect it to work with [ITfoxtec Identity SAML 2.0](https://www.itfoxtec.com/identitysaml2).

You can have a look at [ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2.Saml2RequestException: 'There is not exactly one Assertion element.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62909662/itfoxtec-identity-saml2-saml2requestexception-there-is-not-exactly-one-asserti), maybe that helps.

And look at the received XML there need to be exactly one Assertion element. If the XML is encrypted, you need to provide the decryption key.

Comment: Do I need the decryption key from the Idp and where should I use it?

Comment: The IdP should encrypt to your key. You having the private key and the IdP encrypting with the public key. The key is configured in Saml2Configuration.DecryptionCertificate.

Comment: Hello, I am getting another error now Signature Invalid in response. what could be the issue here? Also I see an boolena option 'validateXmlSignature' . How can I sent it to false??

Comment: The signature have to be validated, that is the actually security of the standard. The problem can be the certificate not matching or the hash algorithm (SHA-1 / SHA-256).